# Ayuden Pofavor con jspdf en Angular

Tags: angularjs

Hola amigos estoy llamando un seletector de un componente dentro de un html de otro componente, la cosa es que estoy usando Html2canvas con Jspdf , yo no quiero mostrar el html de ese componente que estoy llamando y asi poder rederendizarlo , no se si podra. Gracias

```js
  descargarPDF2(){
    this.click=true;
    var data = document.getElementById("pdf2");
    html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
    // Few necessary setting options
    var imgWidth = 208;
    var pageHeight = 295;
    var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
    var heightLeft = imgHeight;

    const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
    this.click=false;
    let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF
    var position = 0;
    pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)
    pdf.save("PDF"); // Generated PDF
    });
  }
```

```html
      <div  id="pdf3">
          <div >
              <app-pdf3>

                </app-pdf3>
          </div>
```

Ts